# Excel VBA code for autosearch

Tags: vba, excel, automation, runtime-error

I need a small help. Below I have mentioned the VBA code that I am using for auto search on google which provides the first link on my excel. The code actually runs pretty well but throws this error "runtime error 91: object variable or with block variable not set" when the google is unable to provide data. This comes often which makes my work a lot harder. To be clear I don't know anything about coding. So kindly help me by creating a loop that can actually skip the non-searchable cell and move onto the other.

```
Sub XMLHTTP()

    Dim url As String, lastRow As Long
    Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object, objResultDiv As Object, objH3 As Object, link As Object
    Dim start_time As Date
    Dim end_time As Date

    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim cookie As String
    Dim result_cookie As String

    start_time = Time
    Debug.Print "start_time:" & start_time

    For i = 2 To lastRow

        url = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1) & "&rnd=" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000)

        Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
        XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
        XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
        XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
        XMLHTTP.send

            Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText
        Set objResultDiv = html.getelementbyid("rso")
        Set objH3 = objResultDiv.getelementsbytagname("H3")(0)
        Set link = objH3.getelementsbytagname("a")(0)


        str_text = Replace(link.innerHTML, "<EM>", "")
        str_text = Replace(str_text, "</EM>", "")

        Cells(i, 2) = str_text
        Cells(i, 3) = link.href
        DoEvents
    Next

    end_time = Time
    Debug.Print "end_time:" & end_time

    Debug.Print "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
    MsgBox "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to trap the error. Reado some [Error Handling](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/). If you want the easy solution, just add `On Error Resume Next` at the beggining of your code but, **we do not encourage to do this never** Just use it if you need your results now, but later on, I strongly suggest to trap the error.

Comment: Can you provide an example search for when fails please?

Comment: Thank you so much it helped a lot.